# Python assign same value in another column if the values in this column match

Tags: python

I imported a table from excel. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/Sophia Wu/Master Data_PMS_1110.xlsx')
table.sheet_names
df = table.parse('Sheet1')
```

The table looks like this:

|     **Fruit         |     Color**      |

|        Apple        |        Red       |

|        Pear         |        Yellow    |

|       Grape         |        Purple    |

|       Apple         |                   |

|      Grape          |                   |

I need to assign the same color if it is the same type of fruit. Since I have more than 10,000 rows in the table, how could I automatically assign the values using Python?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your "table" a Python nested list?

Comment: No. I imported the table from excel.

Comment: @MooingRawr I imported from my excel. I want to use Python to assign the value and then save into another excel sheet

Comment: @MooingRawr import pandas as pd
 
table = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/Sophia Wu/Master Data_PMS_1110.xlsx')
table  This is my code. Yes, can be another excel file.

Comment: @MooingRawr and plus: table.sheet_names;  df = table.parse('Sheet1')

Comment: @MooingRawr OK! Sorry, I'm still new to SO...

Comment: Can you edited your question to include your code? It's okie that you are new. Edited your question and to format your code highlight it and `ctrl`+`k`

Comment: @MooingRawr Sure! Just edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, (untested since at work):

```
colors_to_match = {'Apple':'Red','Pear':'Yellow','Grape':'Purple'}
df['Color'] = df['Fruit'].map(colors_to_match)
```

Basically you are making a look up table, and then mapping it backed on the values in fruit and setting that color to it using the [map function from panda](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

Comment: I actually just gave a few values as an example here. What if I have more than 1000 types of fruits? Is there anyway to deal with that? Thanks!!

Comment: You increase the `colors_to_match` dictionary with what ever the Fruits to Colors are.... just make sure your key (the fruits) are exact match to what's in the excel file. So basically the format of `colors_to_match` is `{'Fruit_Name' : 'Fruit_color'}` you can expend that as big as you want

Comment: @SophiaWu there are ways to generate that `colors_to_match` automatically tho if needs be.... but to do that, we would have to iterate ( go through ) the whole excel file first, and then go back and replace the colors.